# Programatically setting page setup options in Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET Web App which is copying a Report to an Excel Sheet by creating an HTML table and copying the contents.

I want to fit the Excel report into 1 page before firing the print option. This needs to be done programmatically while I'm generating the Excel workbook.

Answer (score 4):

Following is the code that I used to open an Excel workbook and print it with custom printer settings:

```
Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    xl.DisplayAlerts = False
    xl.Workbooks.Open("<FilePath>", Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, _
    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
    Dim sheet As Excel.Worksheet

    Dim ws
    Try
        For Each ws In xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            ws.Select(Type.Missing)
            With ws.PageSetup
                .PaperSize = Excel.XlPaperSize.xlPaperA4
                .Orientation = Excel.XlPageOrientation.xlLandscape
                .Zoom = 80
                .BottomMargin = 0.25
                .LeftMargin = 0.25
                .RightMargin = 0.25
                .TopMargin = 0.25
                .FitToPagesWide = 1
            End With
            ws.PrintOut(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
        Next

    Catch exp As Exception
        MsgBox("Unable to setup printing properties for the sheet." & Chr(13) & "Check if you have printer installed on your machine.", MsgBoxStyle.OKOnly)

    Finally
        xl.Workbooks.Close()
        xl.Quit()
        While (System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xl) > 0)
            ''do nothing
        End While
        xl = Nothing
    End Try
```